# How to get rid of this infinite loop in my code? (Making a number guessing game program)

Tags: perl

I have to create a number guessing game program and have written the code but after inputting my first number guess, the output turns into an infinite loop and keeps repeating forever, so I am forced to shut down my program.  It seems to be an error with my "{}" but I can't figure out where the error is.  I have to let the user guess 8 different times, and am stuck on the 1st guess result because it keeps repeating. Here is my code:

```
print "Welcome to the Perl Whole Number Guessing Game!\n Please enter a number between 1 and 100 and I will tell you if the number you're trying to guess is higher or lower than your guess.  You have up to 8 chances to guess the number.\n";

my ($guess, $target, $counter);    #my variables
$target = (int rand 100) +1;     #must be between 1-100
$counter =1;

#1st guess:
print "Enter guess #$counter:";
chomp ($guess = <>);
while ($guess != $target)
{ if ($guess < $target)
 {
    print "Your guess, $guess, is too low. Try again.\n ";
  }
else
 { print "Your guess, $guess, is too high. Try again.\n ";
}}
until ($guess ==$target)  
{
    print "Congratulations! You guessed the secret number ($target) in $counter tries!\n";
}
$counter ++;
```

...Then that exact code repeats 8 times until the last bit says this:

```
#8th and final guess:
print "Enter guess #$counter:";
chomp ($guess = <>);
while ($guess != $target)
{ if ($guess < $target)
 {print "I'm sorry, you didn't guess the secret number, which was $target.\n";
}
else
 {print "I'm sorry, you didn't guess the secret number, which was $target.\n";
}}
until ($guess ==$target)
{ print "Congratulations! You guessed the secret number ($target) in $counter tries!\n"; 
}
```

I just want to be able to have the code ask me to guess again all 8 times, without having the very first guess go on an infinite loop.

NOTE: I am in a beginning beginning Perl programming class and can't use any fancy, difficult code, basically the simplest solution is best and really the only thing I can kinda understand.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: First of all, do you mean you've copy-pasted the first part of code, like 7 times, one after the other?

Comment: And what is it repeating? "Your guess is too low"? (or "high")

Answer (score 2):

Repeating code is something you should basically never do, except perhaps in very simple cases. Since you have a specific count, just use a `for` loop with a counter.

You should also always use `use warnings; use strict;`, because it will help you avoid simple mistakes and give you informative errors.

Also, your if statement will not detect correct guesses. You will need to use `elsif` (yes, no "e") to also check if the number is too high.

```
my $guesses = 8;
for my $counter (1 .. $guesses) {
    print "Enter guess #$counter:";
    chomp (my $guess = <>);
    if ($guess < $target) {
        print "Your guess, $guess, is too low. Try again.\n ";
    } elsif ($guess > $target) {
        print "Your guess, $guess, is too high. Try again.\n ";
    } else {
        print "Congratulations! You guessed the secret number ($target) in $counter tries!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: If I may, you could do `if ( $guess == $target ) { print "Congrats"; last; }` then all you are left with is an if/else and the code wont keep looping if you win. (TLP I know you could do this, I mention for OP's benefit)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your increment inside your while, first of all.

Repeating code is a terrible way of making a program. That's what loops are for. 
You just need to break out of the loop after the 8th try.

PERL is not my lang of choice, but in most languages, syntax like this will work:

```
while (($guess != $target) && ($count <= 8))
{...}
```

Comment: I just realized, thanks to @Dr. Kameleon, that you need the code I posted, as well as moving your question inside the loop.

Comment: FYI, language is Perl not PERL. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f

Answer (score 0):

`while ($guess != $target)`

means WHILE the user's guess is NOT the random number the computer has "thought of"...
DO what is enclosed in the brackets...

WHICH IS : to print a message (whether the guess was "low", "high" or correct)

Now, think about it... Let's say WE play this game... and I'm the one which has to guess YOUR number... Let's simulate it...

- You think of a number (let's say : target = 34)
- I'm making a guess (let's say : 45)
- WHILE my guess is not correct, tell me "it's too high"

So, you get my point : the rest of the code will NEVER be executed. As you will simply keep telling me that I'm wrong, without letting make another guess...

So, why don't you do... something with that evil... **WHILE**?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know perl, but logically you could put the whole thing in one loop

While (guess != target && wrongAnswer < 8)
{

}

If the answer is not equal to the target increase the wrongAnswer counter.

Answer (score 0):

As the other posters have pointed out, you need to increment somewhere inside your while loop.  Also, keep in mind that you don't need the following code block:

```
until ($guess ==$target)  {
    print "Congratulations! You guessed the secret number ($target) in $counter tries!\n";
}
```

If you reach this point in your code, the condition that $guess is equal to $target will already have been satisfied.  So, checking that again is redundant.  You can skip the until block and go right to the print statement after the while loop.

The most important remaining issue is that you're only asking for input once, before the while block begins. So, during the while block the user never gets the chance to guess a second time.  The guess never changes and the loop will go on forever. To avoid code repetition, you could put the guess code into a subroutine:

```
sub guess {
    print "Enter guess #$counter:";
    chomp( $guess = <> );
}
```

Then call this subroutine once before you get to the while loop:

```
guess();
```

Then once just before the end of your while block:

```
guess();
```

That will reseed the $guess variable before the next pass at the while loop, which will break you out of your infinite loop.  I would have given you an entire code sample, but as this is tagged as "homework", that would rob you of the benefit of working over these issues on your own.  :)